# Добавление тега more (Далее) в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть строчка в файле loop.php темы Sight для WordPress:

```
<div class="post-content"><?php if (function_exists('smart_excerpt')) smart_excerpt(get_the_excerpt(), 55); ?></div>
```

Как я понял, обрезает пост до 55 знаков. Продолжить чтение можно только кликнув по заголовку поста. Мне же нудно добавить тег "Далее" после 55 знаков. Может кто-нибудь сказать, как доработать эту строчку кода? Точно знаю, что обычно используется

```
<?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?>
```

Но  как правильно и куда именно, чтобы всё работало, нужно вставить эту строку.

Подумал было, что проще будет вообще отказать от кода, который 55 знаков оставляет и воспользоваться плагином Auto More. Но нет. Если удалить строчку кода, то записи вообще пропадают. Остаются только заголовки.

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в любую запись и вставьте **<!--more-->** там, где вы бы хотели разделить запись на 2 части.
Если не помогает, попробуйте установить другую тему.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вместо

```
<div class="post-content"><?php if (function_exists('smart_excerpt')) smart_excerpt(get_the_excerpt(), 55); ?></div>
```

напишите

```
<div class="post-content"><?php the_content('Далее...'); ?></div>
```